# Snippets applicable for ArcObjects 10.2.1

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcobjects, visual-studio

I am trying to create ArcGIS desktop add-in using Visual Studio Professional 2012. But when I use ArcGIS Snippets Finder to insert code, I found the applicable versions as follows:

' Applicable ArcGIS Product Versions:
' 9.2
' 9.3
' 9.3.1
' 10.0

But I am using ArcGIS 10.2.1, and the ArcObjects obtained from ArcGIS 10.2.1 Desktop installation CD.

I want to know where can get the snippets applicable for ArcGIS 10.2.1 (or above). And what version of Visual Studio can support ArcObjects for 10.2.1?

Comment: All code snippets for version 10.0 should work in 10.2.1. I'm using VS 2013 with 10.2.1, and I've used 2012 with it too.

Comment: [Officially](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/system-requirements/10.2/0151/01510000006n000000.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_134116909B4B4DB888C65AF8FC67CAB9), 10.2.x works with VS 2010 and VS 2012.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @kenbuja the [ArcObjects SDK system requirements for ArcGIS 10.2.x](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/system-requirements/10.2/index.html#//01510000006n000000#ESRI_SECTION1_134116909B4B4DB888C65AF8FC67CAB9) say that:

> Supported Visual Studio versions include
>
> - Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 (C++) Professional, Premium, Ultimate Edition (with or without Service Pack 1).
> - Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 (C#, VB.NET) Professional, Premium, Ultimate Edition.